# Minecraft 1.7.10 commands to 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a Nacht der Untoten remake with my friends and I was wondering how to make these old commands I used in a previous map in 1.7.10 work in the server we have now in 1.13

```
/scoreboard objectives add zombie stat.killEntity.Zombie zombie

/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar zombie

/testfor @a[score_zombie=0]

/scoreboard players set @a zombie 10

/scoreboard players remove @p zombie 20

/testfor @p[score_zombie_min=15]
```

I tried putting these exact commands into 1.13, however they didn't work. I tried to research but to no avail.

Comment: Well, `testfor` has been completely removed, but there's no good reason for using it in this fashion, probably even back in 1.7 days.

Comment: There are probably 1.8->1.9 command converters online, as well as 1.12->1.13 converters. You could try combining both. Also, it would help if you told us what these commands are supposed to do, often a direct 1:1 translation isn't optimal and it can be solved more easily in 1.13.

Answer (score 1):

First command:

```
/scoreboard objectives add zombie minecraft.killed:minecraft.zombie zombie
```

Third command:

```
/execute if entity @a[scores={zombie=..0}] run <chained command>
```

Fifth command:

```
/execute if entity @p[scores={zombie=15..}] run <chained command>
```

All other commands work identically in Minecraft 1.13

Answer (score 0):

The execute if entity command can be used as testfor sometimes

Comment: Hi Vrtulnik, welcome to Arqade! Would you be willing to elaborate on your answer, perhaps providing a specific example where execute if entity could replace testfor?